# How to Get Specific Number Variable from Text in PHP

Tags: php

I have a php code here

```
<?php   

$txtnum = "Called Number Call Type Call Time Call Duration Call Charges
9231332454834 SMS2/5/2019 9:31:15
AM-- Minutes 0.00 PKR 9230374555790 SMS2/4/2019 8:42:07
PM-- Minutes 0.00 PKR
";

?>
```

Now I want to get output like below

```
9231332454834
9230374555790
```

Please help me how to do this in Php

Comment: Have you tried regular expression? What is the consistency on this format? What parts could change? It's needed to match the pattern.

Comment: before the first number you have a cr/lf, but not before the second. Could this be a copy&paste of a bad formatted csv? Where is the data coming from?

Comment: @Jeff totally agree, it looks like there is no consistency on the data, assuming that it is kinda a tab separated that should match the first row that is the header and I guess each row should start with the "Called Number" that needs to be matched. Bad copied and pasted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `preg_match_all()`. From my end a **non-regex** solution with php functions e.g `array_filter()`

```
<?php
$txtnum = "Called Number Call Type Call Time Call Duration Call Charges 9231332454834 SMS2/5/2019 9:31:15 AM-- Minutes 0.00 PK 9230374555790 SMS2/4/2019 8:42:07 PM-- Minutes 0.00 PKR";
$words = explode(' ', $txtnum);
$result = array_filter($words, 'ctype_digit');
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $result);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
9231332454834 
9230374555790
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/GCViG

Comment: Dear @sunny Output: comes on same line. I want to get every number on new line.

Comment: @NaeemHussain then you can implode it with `\n\r` instead of `PHP_EOL`

Answer (score 1):

something like....

```
<?php

$data = "Called Number Call Type Call Time Call Duration Call Charges
9231332454834 SMS2/5/2019 9:31:15
AM-- Minutes 0.00 PKR 9230374555790 SMS2/4/2019 8:42:07
PM-- Minutes 0.00 PKR
";


preg_match_all ( "/\d{5,13}/", $data, $matches );

print_r ( $matches[0] ); 

?>
```

Comment: Dear Stephanie Temple . I just want to get only value. I don't want to get result in array like: Array ( [0] => 9231332454834 [1] => 9230374555790 ). Please i want to get output  result Like:  9231332454834 new line 9230374555790

Comment: Dear @NaeemHussain: you didn't say what you exactly want, so I'd consider this answer as a good help, as it would give you the two phone numbers! The format you want (after your edit) is just a question of imploding the array to a string with cr/lf.